# Discord.py как отправить embed сообщение в другой канал?

Tags: discord.py

Помогите сделать так чтобы    `emb = discord.Embed` отправлялась в другой канал.

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_channels=True)
async def unwarn(ctx, member: discord.Member, reason: str):
    with open('users.json', 'r') as file:
        data = json.load(file)
        file.close()

    with open('users.json', 'w') as file:
        data[str(member.id)]['WARNS'] -= 1
        json.dump(data, file, indent=4)

        file.close()

    await ctx.message.delete()

    tex = await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(
                title="Успешно",
                description=f"**Пользователю {member.mention} было снято предупреждение по причине {reason}, теперь у него {data[str(member.id)]['WARNS']} предупреждение(й)!**",
                timestamp=ctx.message.created_at,
                color=0x00FF00
                ))

    await sleep(20)
    await tex.delete()

    channel = client.get_channel(928951747370692649)

    emb = discord.Embed(
        title="Логи",
        description=f"*Администратор {author.mention} снял предупреждение пользователю {member.mention} по причине {reason}!*",
        timestamp=message.created_at
        )
    await get(message.guild.text_channels, id=928951747370692649).send(embed=emb)

    await send.channel(embed=emb)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_channels=True)
async def unwarn(ctx, member: discord.Member, reason: str):
    with open('users.json', 'r') as file:
        data = json.load(file)
        file.close()

    with open('users.json', 'w') as file:
        data[str(member.id)]['WARNS'] -= 1
        json.dump(data, file, indent=4)

        file.close()

    await ctx.message.delete()

    tex = await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(
                title="Успешно",
                description=f"**Пользователю {member.mention} было снято предупреждение по причине {reason}, теперь у него {data[str(member.id)]['WARNS']} предупреждение(й)!**",
                timestamp=ctx.message.created_at,
                color=0x00FF00
                ))

    await sleep(20)
    await tex.delete()

    channel = client.get_channel(928951747370692649)

    emb = discord.Embed(
        title="Логи",
        description=f"*Администратор {author.mention} снял предупреждение пользователю {member.mention} по причине {reason}!*",
        timestamp=message.created_at
        )
    await get(message.guild.text_channels, id=928951747370692649).send(embed=emb)

    await channel.send(embed=emb)
```